# How can I use sed to change "\" to "/" in a batch file?

Tags: sed, gnu

I want `\` to be converted into `/` in this variable:

```
PROJECT_PATH=E:\share_folder\Perforce

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('echo %PROJECT_PATH% ^| sed "s/\/\//g"/') DO ( set Replace0=%%a ) 

set WORKSPACE_PATH_FOR_PROP=%Replace0%

echo %WORKSPACE_PATH_FOR_PROP%
```

Result: `E:\share_folder\Perforce`

The result is the same, it did not change `\` into `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This is broken: take a sharp look at

```
sed "s/\/\//g"/
```

where you tell sed to substitute `\\` into `g`, or somesuch, I don't know the quoting rules under Windows. Anyway,

```
sed "s,\\,/,g"
```

should work better. You might need to twiddle the quoting and backslashing, though. If you have it, you might also want to look at `tr` (translate characters) which is tailor-made for this task

```
tr "\\" /
```

Comment: i just replace \ -> / using sed